# angular $scope.$digest throws an error when setInterval fires it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**AngularJS v1.0.6**

I am trying to update this html tag **a**

```
<div ng-app="ModuleName">
   <!-- html code... -->

   <h5> xhr called - <a ng-bind="requestCounter"></a> times</h5>

   <!-- html code... -->
```

With is JavaScript code:

```
angular.module('ModuleName',[])
    .controller('ControllerName', function ($scope){
        var myWorker = new Worker("./client/js/worker.js");
        myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
            $scope.requestCounter = e.data.requestCounter;
        }
        setInterval($scope.$digest,7000);
        /*come code*/
    });
```

This code throws an error - TypeError: t is undefined angular.min.js (line 86)

But the code below works fine:

```
var ControllerName = function ($scope) {
    var myWorker = new Worker("./client/js/worker.js");
    myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
        $scope.requestCounter = e.data.requestCounter;
    }
    setInterval($scope.$digest,7000);
    /*come code*/
}
```

How Can I fix it with **angular.module style**?

**

### Update

**

If I use $apply instead $digest I get this error

```
Error: this.$eval is not a function e.prototype.$apply
@http://localhost/path to angular lib/js/lib/angular.min.js
```

**Update2**

http://plnkr.co/edit/o76t49iId8ELPZuy4gei?p=preview
in this case Worker sends message and setInterval works good. I downloaded new angular.js and everything works fine.
**question is CLOSED**. thx!

Comment: Add a plunker, please. That will make easy to help you ;)

Comment: That would be http://plnkr.co/ for Angular.js among other demos.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WE7sWxPAgx1zFtvgA9Pq?p=preview in this case everything is good, maybe reason is the AngularJS v1.0.6 need newer/ need to try new one

Answer (score 1):

use **$timeout** service instead of **setInterval**
or wrapper like

```
function mySetInterval(callback, time){
   $timeout(function(){
         callback();
         mySetInterval(callback, time);
   }, time);
}
```